# Woocommerce Cart functionality based on case and normal price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have Product

`$price =  $10.27;
$case price  = $80.09
$case quantity = 12
I have Make it working if user will add 12 bottles Cart Price would be $80.09 
But if i add 1 more bottle in cart 12+1 price changes from $80.09 to  $133.51 
I want something like that if there is 13 bottles in cart value should be  $80.09+$10.27 = $90.36;`

Can anyone suggest on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

follow these links. you can get an idea for your custom function.

[add custom fee to woocommerce cart](http://www.remicorson.com/add-custom-fee-to-woocommerce-cart-dynamically/)

[add surcharge to cart](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/add-a-surcharge-to-cart-and-checkout-uses-fees-api/)